# Converting Notepad++ REGEX to .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Working with a pipe-delimited file. Currently, I use Notepad++ find and replace REGEX pattern `^(?:[^|]*\|){5}\K[^|]*` that replaces all lines with an empty string between the 5th and 6th `|`. I'm trying to programmatically do this process, but .NET does not support `\K`. I've tried a few instances of the backward lookup, but I cannot seem to grasp it.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string line2 = null;
    string finalLine = line;
    string[] col = line.Split('|');
    if (col[5] != null)
    {
        line2 = Regex.Replace(line, @"^(?:[^|]*\|){5}\K[^|]*", "");
```

Comment: Saw this on the Internet: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18568/regex-k-pattern-alternatives. Sounds like \K is a workaround for an incomplete regex syntax implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\K` is a "workaround" for regex grammars/engines that don't support anchoring against [look-behind assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

.NET's regex grammar [*has* look-behind assertions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookbehind-assertions) (using the syntax `(?<=subexpression)`), so use them:

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"(?<=^(?:[^|]*\|){5})[^|]*", "")
```

In the context of .NET, this pattern now describes:

```
(?<=               # begin (positive) look-behind assertion
    ^              # match start of string
    (?:            # begin non-capturing group
       [^|]*\|     # match (optional) field value + delimiter
    ){5}           # end of group, repeat 5 times
)                  # end of look-behind assertion
[^|]*              # match any non-delimiters (will only occur where the lookbehind is satisfied)
```

Comment: I want to also point out (to the OP) that .NET's regex engine not only supports Lookbehinds but it also supports non-fixed width Lookbehinds (which is not supported in most other regex engines). That's why that pattern does not work in Notepad++ (although it supports Lookbehinds).

Answer (score 2):

No need using lookbehinds, use capturing groups and backreferences:

```cs
line2 = Regex.Replace(line, @"^((?:[^|]*\|){5})[^|]*", "$1");
```

See [proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%7C%5D*%5C%7C%29%7B5%7D%29%5B%5E%7C%5D*&i=1%7C2%7C3%7C4%7C5%7C6%7C7&r=%241).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (5 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){5}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```